# What is proper way to get array element from return

Tags: php

I found that this code works:

```
private function getSomething() {
  return array('item' => 'one');
}
```

...

```
echo $this->getSomething()['item'];
```

> Output: 'one'

But i can't find in manuals this form of writing. Futhermore Netbeans tells me that it works only in PHP 5.4 and above. Maybe should i assignate variable first and then use it as array?

But this code looks much better and it's in one line...

Finally my question is - can i use this form?

Comment: Once I also came to this problem, and have not found any other solution than assigning to a variable :) If you are using higher PHP version and your project is set up to it in NetBeans, you should not get errors, but in any other way - you should assign

Comment: Yes - you can use this form since PHP 5.4.0 when this feature called function array dereferencing was [introduced](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php).

Comment: Big thanks Jost, your link was everything i need!

Answer (score 1):

Prior to PHP 5.3, you'll need to use a temporary variable.

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];

// or
list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
```

**Source:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88

Comment: But it works for me. :) I'm using php version 5.4.16.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if u know which version of PHP u are working with.

if it has to run on mutiple versions of PHP

u should assign it to a variable first

```
$tmp = $this->getSomething();
echo $tmp[0];
```